# Can I send my friend a pack of weapons?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Yes, I'll be the first to admit, I'm not sure "buying" weapons packs is such a good idea, but it is an option, so I start to wonder... If I were to get Bioware Points, could I gift my friend an equipment pack in Mass Effect 3?

We've not managed to make it past round 3 more than once, since it's just us two. I was considering getting one pack to see if better equipment might help. Ultimately, the minimum bioware point pack is 400 points, and the equipment packs are 80 and 160 points each. Seems like such a waste to do so then, unless I can send a pack or two my friend's way.

Can I gift my friend a weapon pack in Mass Effect 3's multiplayer?

Comment: Do you mean via Origin's interface? Don't know how that works on PC, but on PS3 there's definitely no way to gift things.

Comment: I don't even know how it would work. Via origin, via the game itself, I don't really care as long as the end result is the same. We are on PC though.

Comment: It should be noted, 2 SPECTRE packs and a veteran pack (or 5 veteran packs or whatever) on one account is hardly a waste, since the contents are random, and redundant weapons/upgrades/classes simply make the ones you have better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the Origin interface (online/desktop) and Bioware Social Network a gifted purchase is not possible at this time. It's also not possible within the game itself. Any transferable purchase has to be done with a physical item (gift card) or code.

EA does however provide the capability to buy virtual items and in game currency as a physical purchase. This could be in the form of a gift card or as included in a retail box copy of a game. Origin is designed to allow you to redeem these physical purchases through them.

Check out http://eacashcard.com. There you will find some examples of 'brick-and-mortar' retail stores where gift cards are available. Among the list of games shown on the site, Mass Effect 2 purchases are available but not Mass Effect 3.

At this time the most effective way to gift may be to give your friend the $ to purchase the points outright.